# How do you force form validation for all fields on submit?

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation

I need to be able to validate certain fields even if they were never touched by the user. Some fields are required, however, at least as I've experienced it so far, a required field is not invalidated on **submit**: it is only invalidated on **blur**. So if the user never actually touches a field (or any fields, for that matter), and hits submit, the form will validate successfully and submit, causing server-side validation errors.

My question regarding AngularJS form validation: **How do you FORCE the entire form to validate on submission, regardless of whether a user has actually touched any form fields or not?**

I have a bunch of forms, and on most forms there are several required fields, as well as fields with min/max and maxlength requirements. If I just build an AngularJS form, apply directives like `ng-required`, and hit submit, the forms always submit. Nothing stops it.

I need my forms to NOT submit if required fields are empty, regardless of whether the user has actually touched them and left (which is the only way a blur event will fire, and therefor the only way those fields will be validated.)

Using the "disabled" submit button approach is unacceptable for me here.

Resources I've referenced:

- [Processing Forms in AngularJS](https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/processing-forms-angularjs)

  - Issue: The `if (form.$invalid) return;` idiom does not work. I encounter the error *"TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined"*
- [Form Validation: The AngularJS Way](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/form-validation-the-angularjs-way)

  - While I think this is an interesting approach, our client does not want thousands of little small ajax requests performing inline (i.e. onblur) validation against their database server. So the approach for things like verifying username uniqueness with a `unique` directive is not an option for us.

---

For reference, here is my current submit function in my controller:

**The Form:**

```
<div ng-switch on="state" ng-controller="OwnerCtrl">

<!-- A whole bunch of other layout and informational junk -->

    <form name="ownerForm" novalidate ng-submit="submit(ownerForm)">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3 control-group" ng-class="{error: ownerForm.FirstName.$dirty && ownerForm.FirstName.$invalid }">
                <label class="control-label" for="FirstName" ng-class="">First Name</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="input-block-level" data-val="true" data-val-required="First Name is required"
                               id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" type="text" ng-required ng-model="owner.firstName"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- A BUNCH of other form controls here -->

        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
                <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="back()">
                    <span ng-hide="transitionBack"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-white"></i><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Back</span>
                    <span ng-show="transitionBack">Loading...</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                    <span ng-hide="transitionForward"></span>Continue<i class="icon-chevron-right icon-white"></i><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-white"></i></span>
                    <span ng-show="transitionForward">Loading...</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
<div>
```

**The controller:**

```
var owner = angular.module("Owner", []);

owner.controller("OwnerCtrl", ["$scope", "$location", "$log", function($scope, $location, $log) {

    $scope.owner = {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        middleInitial: "",
        birthDate: null,
        ssn: "",
        phoneNumber: ""
    };

    $scope.formSubmitted = false;

    $scope.submit = function(form) {
        // Found this on a blog somewhere, just an attempt to FORCE form validation even
        // on elements that have never been touched by the uyser
        for (var field in form) {
            // look at each form input with a name attribute set
            // checking if it is pristine and not a '$' special field
            if (field[0] != '$' && form[field].$pristine) {
                form[field].$setViewValue(
                    form[field].$modelValue
                );
            }
        }

        $scope.formSubmitted = true;

        if (form.$invalid)
            return;
    }
}
```

I've removed other unnecessary bits of html and js from the examples, to keep them concise. This is the only code that matters for the issue at hand.

As a side note. I am currently passing in the form, rather than using `$scope.ownerForm.$valid`. Despite the fact that I have indeed named my form, `$scope.ownerForm` does not work. The form property is undefined, but seemingly ONLY when I try to access the $valid or $invalid properties on it. Ironically, `$scope.ownerForm[field]` actually worked (originally, before I started passing in the form object). It only seemed to fail when I access the `$valid`/`$invalid` properties.

---

**UPDATE:**

So, it seems my problems are even deeper than having the form validate on submit. It actually appears as though my form is not validating, period. I just went through my entire form, filled it out with all invalid data (too long strings, non-numeric data in numeric fields, and left required fields empty. Angular SHOULD be validating these fields as soon as they blur, as far as I understand. Not one single field invalidated. Debugging my submit function, the form is currently marked as valid. Furthermore, I went through each of the fields with Chrome's dev tools, and all of the fields are marked dirty, and *valid*, not invalid.

It seems required/ng-required and all the other form validation attributes are being ignored...however also in Chrome's dev tools, I can see functions attached to each of the input properties that were added to the form object. On all the required fields, for example, I can see a function that is apparently designed to validate that requirement. There is also something in the $parsers array.

I'm completely baffled. *Why is my form validation not working?*

Comment: this should not have been closed. it is a different question

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `ng-disabled` approach, I would go with the [`ng-submit`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) approach; you could launch your custom validate function on submit, checking the fields "manually" for errors. Something like:

```
// inside the controller
$scope.onSubmit = function($event) {
  // check for errors; if wrong return/preventDefault/doTheRightThing
  // else continue
};
//...
```

and the HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="onSubmit">
  <!-- form fields -->
</form>
```

Comment: I've tried this approach. Despite having both `required` and `ng-required` (as well as others) on my form input elements, the necessary validation is not kicking in. I've even tried to force validation (I'll update my question with my submit function implementation for clarity), and even then my form still does not actually get properly invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrect. The validation state of the form elements, and of the form itself, is constantly up-to-date. Everytime the user enters something in an element, or everytime the underlying model changes, the `$invalid`/`$valid` attributes of the elements and of the form are updated.

So, in your submit method, you just need to check if the form's `$valid` attribute is true or false, and act accordingly.

If you got "Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined", then it means that you didn't give a name to your form, or that you used an incorrect name in your controller. Show us your code to help us diagnose the problem.

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ImnC4d2WXNdsDqwNlTUa?p=preview

Comment: And what if the model does not change? We are updating our process, some source data in the database may not be valid under new rules. A user logs in, the form populates with their current data, they click "Next"...and they continue, when the form validation should find the errors and stop them from continuing. The model never changes, the user may never even touch the form (except for the button)...validation does NOT occur in that case (at least, it is not for me.)

Comment: We can make the issue even simpler. I load up my form. I do not touch it, no data is preloaded, but form fields are not touched and models are not changed. I click "Next"...and form validation does not kick in. My problem here is that AngularJS form validation is event driven. It will not occur unless something changes. Even my little loop in my code in the question doesn't seem to trigger required fields, which should validate regardless, to actually become marked as invalid. They get marked as dirty, but not invalid.  That seems very wrong to me. A required field should be validated...

Comment: ...REGARDLESS of whether the field blurred or the model for it changed. This is the behavior I'm experiencing. Should I be experiencing something else? Or is this just how angular works?

Comment: Click on the link in my answer. Press the submit button. Look at what is displayed: the form is invalid. Although you haven't touched any input fields. The validation is event driven, and displaying the initial values is already an event that sets the validity of the form. Regarding your code: ng-required expects a boolean value. Try to write a plunkr that reproduces the problem, just as I wrote a plunkr showing that validation works fine.

Comment: @JBL I checked out your plunker the first time around. I have tried using a variety of approaches to required. I've just used `required`, `ng-required`, and `ng-required="true"`, all to no avail. Same issue occurs with `ng-maxlength="40"`, which is on a bunch of my other form fields. It seems something is interfering with AngularJS' form validation in my project, so I guess I'll just have to go digging around in the pile of needles for a piece of hay...blindfolded.